# Azure Bot Emulator Error : POST 401 directline.postActivity

Tags: azure, botframework

I am developing a bot using Microsoft bot builder (C# LUIS template) and setting up Bot Emulator to debug my code locally but when I send message on bot emulator it gives below error:

> POST 401 directline.postActivity

Emulator JSON Inspector giving more details which seems related to authentication

> "BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!"

For running code locally I am not passing any value for below settings in web.config and also not passing any value for app id and password from emulator.

```
<add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="" />
```

I checked all web.config appsetting are same as Application Settings in azure WebApp.  Also using InMemory store for local debugging, below is code from global.asax.cs

```
var store = new InMemoryDataStore();
```

Endpoint url is also correct in emulator

```
http://localhost:3984/api/messages
```

I also installed ngrok but no luck.

Comment: Ah, my apologies it was my silly mistake while copying Application Settings values from azure web app to AppSettings in web.config file. I corrected AppSettings values which fixed this issue.

Comment: You could post a reply of your solution and mark it as answer to let others find, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was issue with AppSettings in web.config file. So if you see this error make sure you have correctly provided key-value under AppSettings in web.config file

Comment: In my web.config no appkey is there. below is my web.config.   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\EchoBot.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>   Please note that, I have downloaded the source code from Azure Portal.

Comment: In my case, I did not specify MS App Id/pass in the emulator. After copying values from AppSettings.json worked for me.